# How to copy content from worksheet to another

Tags: excel

I have two worksheet, one in language A, one in language B with the same order (column and row). Now i want to combine these 02 worksheet into one with bi-language. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

This code combines each cell from the first and second worksheets with a line break between the values and places the resulting text on the third sheet:

```
Sub CombineSheets(sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet)
    Dim lNumRows As Long, lNumCols As Long
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    lNumRows = sh1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If sh2.UsedRange.Rows.Count > lNumRows Then lNumRows = sh2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lNumCols = sh1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    If sh2.UsedRange.Columns.Count > lNumCols Then lNumCols = sh2.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    For lRow = 1 To lNumRows
        For lCol = 1 To lNumCols
            dest.Cells(lRow, lCol) = sh1.Cells(lRow, lCol) & vbCrLf & sh2.Cells(lRow, lCol)
        Next lCol
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Note: This assumes that the `UsedRange` starts at `A1` on both worksheets.